# Create "Windows installer" for Python lib

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, windows-installer, xmlsec

I have compiled a PyXMLSec lib successful on Ubuntu. I want to create a windows-installer for this lib (i.e PyXMLSec-win32-python27.exe). Can I create it from my Ubuntu or it must be from Win32? How can I create it? I prefer from Ubuntu because in Windows, I have some bugs.

Thanks.

Comment: you will need to set the correct flags to target x86 on your gcc or g++ line... (i thik it might be `-target=x86`)

Comment: If you have bugs on Windows, doing it on Ubuntu won't fix them. Fix them first, then worry about an installer.

Comment: My PyXMLSec on Windows now can run well. Could you please explain more how to create an installer from Windows compiled lib?

Comment: As far as I know you must build the exe on Windows. You may have some luck with Wine and the free developer tools. But I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

You should build and test the installer on Windows. (If you don't test it on Windows, you don't know it works on Windows.)

The commonly used free installation software products used for making Windows installers typically include [Wix](http://www.wix.com) and [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). For ease of use, I prefer Inno Setup; it has some free GUIs (linked to from the site itself) for creating the setup scripts used to build the installer, is pretty flexible without any custom work on your part, and easily extendable using it's built-in Object Pascal-based scripting language.

Wix, however, supports building MSI-based installers that use Windows Installer. MSI installs are often required by corporate network administrators because they allow pushing the installation out to computers in the network domain easily. It's harder to work with unless you're pretty familiar with it, so it may not be suitable for a one-off installer requirement like you seem to need.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make an installation file for my python source code"

You have to use NSIS, InnoSetup, BitRock Installer, IzPack or equivalent to produce a platform installer. So you have to take the binary result produced on the first part and package it for os distribution. Almost all the installer systems are thinked for Windows systems. Cross platform : Zero Install, IzPack ... If you use IzPack you can have a cross platform installer paying the price of including a jvm.

And i Believe This >> [HELP](http://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/) Can be Light of Your Way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for [Build Distribution](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html):

```
python setup.py bdist --format=msi
```